# Unable to write data to firebase android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am unable to write any data to my firebase database, however it is connected. My rules of both read and write are set to true, and I added the required SDK's but I still cannot add data.

```
    Button RegisterBttn;
    EditText userEmail, userPassword, userName;

    //Firebase setup
    FirebaseDatabase mydatabase;
    DatabaseReference users;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_page);

        RegisterBttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registerBttn);

        //Firebase
        mydatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        users = mydatabase.getReference("Users");

        userEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailRegisterText);
        userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordRegisterText);
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameRegisterText);

        RegisterBttn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                final User user = new User(userName.getText().toString(),
                        userPassword.getText().toString(),
                        userEmail.getText().toString());

                users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        if(dataSnapshot.child(user.getUserName()).exists()) {
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterPage.this, "The Username already exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            users.child(user.getUserName()).setValue(user);
                          // Log.i("Info", "Button Pressed");
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterPage.this, "Registered successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                       // Toast.makeText(RegisterPage.this, "Error registering", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

        });
    }
}
```

I have a seperate class for "User", containing username, pass and email.
I am using Realtime DB. The rules are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

Here is the Logcat:

```
2020-04-11 23:30:54.483 25114-25114/? I/xample.fitnote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2020-04-11 23:30:54.563 25114-25114/? E/xample.fitnote: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2020-04-11 23:30:54.571 25114-25114/? W/xample.fitnote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2020-04-11 23:30:55.411 25114-25114/com.example.fitnotes V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
2020-04-11 23:30:55.412 25114-25114/com.example.fitnotes I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2020-04-11 23:30:55.440 25114-25114/com.example.fitnotes W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:124): avc: denied { write } for name="property_service" dev="tmpfs" ino=620 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c134,c256,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:property_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
2020-04-11 23:30:55.456 25114-25156/com.example.fitnotes D/libEGL: Emulator has host GPU support, qemu.gles is set to 1.
2020-04-11 23:30:55.456 25114-25156/com.example.fitnotes W/libc: Unable to set property "qemu.gles" to "1": connection failed; errno=13 (Permission denied)
2020-04-11 23:30:55.669 25114-25156/com.example.fitnotes D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
2020-04-11 23:30:55.694 25114-25156/com.example.fitnotes D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
2020-04-11 23:30:55.696 25114-25156/com.example.fitnotes D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
2020-04-11 23:30:55.700 25114-25114/com.example.fitnotes V/FA: onActivityCreated
2020-04-11 23:30:55.806 25114-25114/com.example.fitnotes W/xample.fitnote: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-04-11 23:30:55.806 25114-25114/com.example.fitnotes W/xample.fitnote: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2020-04-11 23:30:55.945 25114-25167/com.example.fitnotes D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2020-04-11 23:30:56.021 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes W/xample.fitnote: Verification of java.lang.Long com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzap.zzbz() took 116.979ms
2020-04-11 23:30:56.201 25114-25154/com.example.fitnotes D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdbf3f320, tid 25154
2020-04-11 23:30:56.209 25114-25154/com.example.fitnotes D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2020-04-11 23:30:56.225 25114-25154/com.example.fitnotes W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2020-04-11 23:30:56.227 25114-25154/com.example.fitnotes D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 0 0
2020-04-11 23:30:56.227 25114-25154/com.example.fitnotes D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xdbf1a120: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2020-04-11 23:30:56.229 25114-25154/com.example.fitnotes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdbf1a120: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdbf0f1a0)
2020-04-11 23:30:56.253 25114-25154/com.example.fitnotes W/Gralloc3: mapper 3.x is not supported
2020-04-11 23:30:56.266 25114-25154/com.example.fitnotes D/HostConnection: createUnique: call
2020-04-11 23:30:56.267 25114-25154/com.example.fitnotes D/HostConnection: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xdbf3f460, tid 25154
2020-04-11 23:30:56.267 25114-25154/com.example.fitnotes D/HostConnection: HostComposition ext ANDROID_EMU_CHECKSUM_HELPER_v1 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v2 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v3 ANDROID_EMU_native_sync_v4 ANDROID_EMU_dma_v1 ANDROID_EMU_direct_mem ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v1 ANDROID_EMU_host_composition_v2 ANDROID_EMU_YUV420_888_to_NV21 ANDROID_EMU_YUV_Cache ANDROID_EMU_async_unmap_buffer GL_OES_EGL_image_external_essl3 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_KHR_texture_compression_astc_ldr ANDROID_EMU_gles_max_version_3_0 
2020-04-11 23:30:56.268 25114-25154/com.example.fitnotes D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: Ask for block of size 0x1000
2020-04-11 23:30:56.268 25114-25154/com.example.fitnotes D/eglCodecCommon: allocate: ioctl allocate returned offset 0x3ffff6000 size 0x2000
2020-04-11 23:30:56.294 25114-25154/com.example.fitnotes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdbf1a120: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdbf0f1a0)
2020-04-11 23:30:56.313 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes V/FA: App measurement collection enabled
2020-04-11 23:30:56.314 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes V/FA: App measurement enabled for app package, google app id: com.example.fitnotes, 1:247538218926:android:4af44b308740275bc97a3f
2020-04-11 23:30:56.323 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 21028
2020-04-11 23:30:56.323 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2020-04-11 23:30:56.324 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.example.fitnotes
2020-04-11 23:30:56.324 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2020-04-11 23:30:56.328 25114-25154/com.example.fitnotes D/eglCodecCommon: setVertexArrayObject: set vao to 0 (0) 1 0
2020-04-11 23:30:56.675 25114-25125/com.example.fitnotes I/xample.fitnote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 12091(2542KB) AllocSpace objects, 9(244KB) LOS objects, 49% free, 1893KB/3787KB, paused 11.909ms total 108.785ms
2020-04-11 23:30:56.824 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2020-04-11 23:30:56.864 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-04-11 23:30:56.868 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 23076629
2020-04-11 23:30:56.881 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
2020-04-11 23:30:56.919 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-04-11 23:30:56.920 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-04-11 23:30:56.920 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes D/FA: Connected to remote service
2020-04-11 23:30:56.921 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
2020-04-11 23:31:00.791 25114-25114/com.example.fitnotes W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@1e91d36
2020-04-11 23:31:00.799 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 4674
2020-04-11 23:31:00.815 25114-25114/com.example.fitnotes V/FA: onActivityCreated
2020-04-11 23:31:00.928 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes V/FA: Activity paused, time: 23081303
2020-04-11 23:31:01.142 25114-25154/com.example.fitnotes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdbf1a120: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdbf0f1a0)
2020-04-11 23:31:01.170 25114-25154/com.example.fitnotes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdbf1a120: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdbf0f1a0)
2020-04-11 23:31:01.209 25114-25154/com.example.fitnotes D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xdbf1a120: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xdbf0f1a0)
2020-04-11 23:31:01.271 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 23081552
2020-04-11 23:31:03.148 25114-25114/com.example.fitnotes I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 3084 bytes, containing 1 windows, 18 views
2020-04-11 23:31:06.509 25114-25153/com.example.fitnotes V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2020-04-11 23:31:10.941 25114-25114/com.example.fitnotes I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 3132 bytes, containing 1 windows, 18 views
2020-04-11 23:31:14.486 25114-25114/com.example.fitnotes I/Info: Button Pressed
2020-04-11 23:31:14.486 25114-25114/com.example.fitnotes I/Info: uu
```

Comment: Could you add your rules as well? and maybe any error logs?

Comment: Specifically what rules? And there are no errors in the Logcat

Comment: Oh sorry. I was referring to the database rules, though that seems unlikely that's an issue if there we're no logs.

Comment: I am using Realtime DB. I have the read and write rules set to true

Comment: "My rules of both read and write are set to true" -> please add those security rules to your questions as well.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added them in the question.

Comment: Let's see if we can reduce the scope of the problem. If you add a line `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("test").setValue(true);` right after the call to `setContentView` and run the app again, does it write `true` to `/test` in your database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No, it does not write anything.

Comment: That sounds like your app isn't able to connect to the database. I recommend [enabling debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and checking its output in logcat for a hint of what's going wrong.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I added the logcat in the question. Please take a look.

Comment: I don't see anything specific to the database in there. Please find a way to only share what is relevant to that, for example by comparing the logcat output with database logging enabled with the output you get when you don't enable database logging.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen How can I enable database logging?

Comment: I included a link to the API docs in the comment where I recommended that you enable it. That should translate to `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setLogLevel(Logger.Level.DEBUG)` or something close to that.